# facebook graph api get user page feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get user public posts, who is not authorized in my application.
For example this is user : https://www.facebook.com/740273079  who knows nothing about my application. What i want to get his public posts, which is vissible on his wall publicly. I am trying to use graph api
[image]

but as  you can see it returns nothing. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only get access to public posts of a user who authorized your App with the `user_posts` permission. Public posts of users who did NOT authorize your App are none of your business.

Comment: Maybe use httpwebrequest for login facebook ,then navigate to specific user and download  his/her page ? But i can't login from code

Comment: that is not allowed. if it's not possible with the API, don't do it. and again, if the user did not authorize it, it's none of your business. you would not be allowed to do anything with the data without his permission anyway.